# Android get the nearby latitude longitude from sqlite based from the location of user

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-sqlite, android-location

I'm creating an app composed of google map and listview of places under the map. I decided to add a button wherein if the user clicks it, nearby location will appear based on the location of the user in listview and the markers will appear in the map. I dont have an idea how to do it. Please help me.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

GoogleMap map;

List<LocationModel> GetLocation;
Context context = this;
DatabaseHelper dbhelper;
DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
ListView lv;
View yourListView,yourProfileView;
Button button;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);


    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View convertView) {

            findNearByPlaces();

        }

    });

    try{
        dbhelper.createDataBase();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        dbhelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    GetLocation = dbhelper.getLocation();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lv.setAdapter(new ViewAdapter());

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            LatLng latlngtofocus = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(GetLocation.get(i).getlatitude()),  Double.parseDouble(GetLocation.get(i).getlongitude()));

            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlngtofocus, 17.0f));

            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latlngtofocus);
            //adding marker to the map
            map.addMarker(markerOptions);


            yourListView = findViewById(R.id.layout);
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) yourListView.getParent();
            parent.removeView(yourListView);
            // inflate your profile view (or get the reference to it if it's already inflated)
            yourProfileView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.profile_location, parent, false);
            // add it to the parent
            parent.addView(yourProfileView);

        }


    });



    //To get MapFragment reference from xml layout
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    //To get map object
    map = mapFragment.getMap();
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

   /* //to show current location in the map
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), latLng.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });*/

    //To setup location manager
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //To request location updates
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 1, this);

}

private void findNearByPlaces() {
    Location mLastLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()); //ERROR

    long currentLat = mLastLocation.getLatitude(); //ERROR
    long currentLng = mLastLocation.getLongitude(); //ERROR

    List<LocationModel> nearByLocationList = new ArrayList<LocationModel>();
    for(int i =0 ; i< GetLocation.size(); i++ ){
        if(isInRange(currentLat,currentLng,GetLocation.getlat(),
                GetLocation.getLong())){//ERROR
            nearByLocationList.add(GetLocation.get(i));
        }
    }
    showDataOnMap(nearByLocationList);
}

private boolean isInRange(long currentLat, long currentlongi,long databaseLat, long databaselongi)
{
    Location loc1 = new Location(currentLat,currentlongi); loc1.setLatitude(lat1);//ERROR
    loc1.setLongitude(lon1);
    Location loc2 = new Location(databaseLat, databaselongi); loc2.setLatitude(lat2);//ERROR
    loc2.setLongitude(lon2);
    float distanceInMeters = loc1.distanceTo(loc2);
    if(distanceInMeters <= 50)// your given range
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

private void showDataOnMap(List<LocationModel> nearByLocationList){
    for(int i =0 ; i< nearByLocationList.size(); i++){
        LatLng latlngtofocus = new      LatLng(Double.parseDouble(nearByLocationList.get(i).getlatitude()),     Double.parseDouble(nearByLocationList.get(i).getlongitude()));

        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlngtofocus, 17.0f));

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latlngtofocus);
        //adding marker to the map
        map.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    //To clear map data
    map.clear();

    //To hold location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    //To create marker in map
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("My Location");
    //adding marker to the map
    map.addMarker(markerOptions);

    //opening position with some zoom level in the map
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17.0f));
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

/****************************************************************************************
 *                                      CUSTOM LIST
 ****************************************************************************************/
public class ViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ViewAdapter() {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return GetLocation.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_country,null);
        }

        final TextView location = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.location);
        final TextView latitude = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.latitude);
        final TextView longitude = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.longitude);

        location.setText(GetLocation.get(position).getlocation());
        latitude.setText(GetCountry.get(position).getlatitude());
        longitude.setText(GetCountry.get(position).getlongitude());

        return convertView;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(yourProfileView != null && yourProfileView.getParent() != null) {
        // remove your profile view
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) yourProfileView.getParent();
        parent.removeView(yourProfileView);

        // a reference to yourListView has to be saved somewhere; just get it

        // add your listview to the parent
        parent.addView(yourListView);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Do not remove the list view. Just do `setVisibilty(View.GONE)`.

Comment: My goal is to create a button that has a function to display the location near the user and the data of latitude and longitude is in the sqlite. I dont have an idea how to do it.

Comment: get all data from sqlite and get your current lat long from location api. After that filter near by location, get distance between your current location and given lat long in sqlite. Then keep only those lat long in filtered list which are in given range of you. Have you got my point?

Comment: dont know how to code it since im only beginner to android. and my code above is based only from the codes that i'd researched

Comment: call like below:
int nearByRangeInMeterToSearch = 50;
List<LocationModel> NearByLocation = new ArrayList<LocationModel>;
GetLocation = dbhelper.getLocation();
for(int i =0; i < GetLocation.size(); i++){
      if(isInRange(GetLocation.get(i), myLat, MYlong)){
       NearByLocation.add(GetLocation.get(i));
       }
}

// show filtered list in map

Comment: cant understand sorry. can u please arrange it like my post which is in proper coding.

Comment: private boolean isInRange(){ Location loc1 = new Location(""); loc1.setLatitude(lat1); loc1.setLongitude(lon1); Location loc2 = new Location(""); loc2.setLatitude(lat2); loc2.setLongitude(lon2); float distanceInMeters = loc1.distanceTo(loc2); }

Answer (score -1):

```
button.setOnClickListener(){

   findNearByPlaces();
}

private void findNearByPlaces(){
Location mLastLocation =//http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html
 long currentLat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
  long currentLng = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

List<LocationModel> nearByLocationList = new ArrayList<LocationModel>();
for(int i =0 ; i< GetLocation.size(); i++ ){
      if(isInRange(currentLat,currentLng,GetLocation.getlat(),
            GetLocation.getLong())){
                     nearByLocationList.add(GetLocation.get(i));
      }
 }

   showDataOnMap(nearByLocationList);
}

private boolean isInRange(long currentLat, long currentlongi,long databaseLat, long databaselongi)
{ 
Location loc1 = new Location(currentLat,currentlongi); loc1.setLatitude(lat1); 
loc1.setLongitude(lon1); 
Location loc2 = new Location(databaseLat, databaselongi); loc2.setLatitude(lat2); 
loc2.setLongitude(lon2); 
float distanceInMeters = loc1.distanceTo(loc2);
if(distanceInMeters <= 50)// your given range
 return true;
else 
 return false;
} 


private void showDataOnMap(List<LocationModel> nearByLocationList){
for(int i =0 ; i< nearByLocationList.size(); i++){
    LatLng latlngtofocus = new      LatLng(Double.parseDouble(nearByLocationList.get(i).getlatitude()),     Double.parseDouble(nearByLocationList.get(i).getlongitude()));

                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlngtofocus, 17.0f));

                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(latlngtofocus);
                //adding marker to the map 
                map.addMarker(markerOptions);
}
}
```

Comment: why Location mLastLocation = has no value? also i got error in these lines -> long currentLat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
->long currentLng = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
->if(isInRange(currentLat,currentLng,GetLocation.getlat(),
                    GetLocation.getLong())){
->Location loc1 = new Location(currentLat,currentlongi); loc1.setLatitude(lat1);
        loc1.setLongitude(lon1);
        Location loc2 = new Location(databaseLat, databaselongi); loc2.setLatitude(lat2);
        loc2.setLongitude(lon2);

Comment: i have given a link in front of mLastLocation from where you can copy code here. see that link and read how to get current location. I have given example that you can get current lat long from this link help.

Comment: but in my code public void onLocationChanged(Location location), i already get my current location

Comment: ok then use that lat long. then there is no need for it. I am assuming that you will put current lat long here. if you have then use those.

Comment: you do not know anything in android? You are asking so many basic things. Why do you not remove error yourself. Read documentation of android regarding this.